# How can I make for an environment to remain contracted?

Tags: environments, texmaker, sourcecode

When I am editing my document in TexMaker I can do the following

[image]

But when I close TexMaker and I open it after, it occurs that the theorems and definitions don't remain contracted, how can I make for they remain contracted?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Your question isn't completely clear, but I assume you mean that there is space (more than you want) between these different environments.  That is because they are all defined as standalone elements that math editors consider should be set off for best understanding by a reader.  What I see in your example is a proof that has multiple parts.  For that, just a single proof environment, containing an enumerated list, may be an appropriate format.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I agree with you that the question isn't completely clear. I would have thought that the question pertains directly to TeXMaker and that it asks how keep "code folding" intact when closing and reopening a file. It certainly would help if the OP clarified the objective of the question.

Comment: Mico, yes, you got it, I refer to what you say, I want to keep "code folding". Can you help me?

Comment: As far I can see, you only can do bulk folding  only in the actual session and only for some section level (Edit>Fold all>Subsections, for instance) but no in environments.